Create a measure that ignores table filtering and aggregates to a higher level in pivot table - DAX/Power Pivot
I am attempting to rebuild a backend for an excel dashboard with power pivot and need to create a series of columns that give a category level total per personal ID.  This means the sum of that persons Pod/Team is listed in the persons row.  I have many tables, but the ones involved are a roster tab which includes the pod/team for each ID as well as other personal information, and a table with production data.  The tables are joined by ID, TTMR[ID]1-->*Prod[ID].
Table 1: Roster



ID
Name
Pod
Team




123456
Jane Doe
Sharks
Monty


654321
John Doe
Jets
Capps


456321
Jim Doe
Dolphins
Capps



The hierarchy goes: Department>>Team>>Pod>>ID
Table 2: Production



ID
Daily Prod




123456
25


654321
32


456321
19



Result Desired:



ID
Name
Pod
Team
Production
Pod Prod
Team Prod




123456
Jane Doe
Sharks
Monty
25
25
25


654321
John Doe
Jets
Capps
32
32
51


456321
Jim Doe
Dolphins
Capps
19
19
51



The problem I'm getting is when I use calculate, the measure saves fine but when I go to populate it in the table it tells me it is either invalid, or that it cannot convert "pod name here" to type true/false.
I couldn't fit all the different syntax I've tried at this point.  I've tried summarize, calculate, calculate with crossfilter, just filter, sumx ... I was getting pretty desperate.  I need this to be one solid pivot table.  There are actually several of these pod and team columns with different values so I really need to know how to get the data to aggregate in general to a higher level, and deposit the result on each line.
Please let me know what you need to help me with this.


create relationship between two tables.

then create measure


Production = sum(Production[Daily Prod])
Pod Prod = sum(Production[Daily Prod])
MEASURE =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Production[Daily Prod] ),
    ALL ( Roster ),
    Roster[Team] = MAX ( Roster[Team] )
)



This does not work in power pivot.  You have created the table in power BI, I am in excel.  I get an error telling me I cannot use MAX in a true/false statement when I plug this in.

"This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'Calculation error in measure 'TTMR'[Pod:Daily]: A function 'MAX' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.'."

then you can try this
Measure 1:=CALCULATE(sum([Daily Prod]),ALLEXCEPT(Roster,Roster[Team]))

